# Category comparison

Tags: pandas, dataframe, quantile

I have the following dataframe:

```
{
    'views_per_day': {0: 37, 1: 26, 2: 10, 3: 17, 4: 5, 5: 13, 6: 5, 7: 15, 8: 7, 9: 7, 10: 3, 11: 13, 12: 9, 13: 27, 14: 13, 15: 6, 16: 17, 17: 12, 18: 9, 19: 16, 20: 6, 21: 11, 22: 5, 23: 12, 24: 10, 25: 4, 26: 12, 27: 8, 28: 9, 29: 8, 30: 11, 31: 18, 32: 15, 33: 4, 34: 8, 35: 7, 36: 8, 37: 8, 38: 5, 39: 8, 40: 10, 41: 33, 42: 8, 43: 7, 44: 7, 45: 7, 46: 7, 47: 7, 48: 6, 49: 7, 50: 6, 51: 5, 52: 3, 53: 6, 54: 13, 55: 6, 56: 6, 57: 7, 58: 6, 59: 5, 60: 4, 61: 5, 62: 6, 63: 6, 64: 3, 65: 6, 66: 6, 67: 4, 68: 5, 69: 4, 70: 6, 71: 5, 72: 5, 73: 3, 74: 4, 75: 5, 76: 8, 77: 30, 78: 9, 79: 5, 80: 5, 81: 6, 82: 5, 83: 4, 84: 7, 85: 4, 86: 4, 87: 5, 88: 3, 89: 3, 90: 7, 91: 3, 92: 4, 93: 8, 94: 2, 95: 3, 96: 5, 97: 4, 98: 4, 99: 4, 100: 4, 101: 4, 102: 4, 103: 3, 104: 4, 105: 6, 106: 3, 107: 3, 108: 3, 109: 3, 110: 3, 111: 3, 112: 4, 113: 3, 114: 3, 115: 4, 116: 3, 117: 3, 118: 2, 119: 3, 120: 3, 121: 2, 122: 4, 123: 4, 124: 4, 125: 26, 126: 3, 127: 3, 128: 5, 129: 3, 130: 2, 131: 4, 132: 3, 133: 4, 134: 3, 135: 4, 136: 3, 137: 3, 138: 5, 139: 2, 140: 5, 141: 3, 142: 3, 143: 4, 144: 3, 145: 3, 146: 4, 147: 4, 148: 7, 149: 3, 150: 3, 151: 3, 152: 2, 153: 3, 154: 12, 155: 3, 156: 2, 157: 3, 158: 2, 159: 2, 160: 3, 161: 4, 162: 2, 163: 2, 164: 4, 165: 3, 166: 3, 167: 5, 168: 1, 169: 2, 170: 11, 171: 3, 172: 2, 173: 4, 174: 4, 175: 2, 176: 6, 177: 2, 178: 4, 179: 2, 180: 3, 181: 2, 182: 2, 183: 2, 184: 2, 185: 2, 186: 2, 187: 2, 188: 3, 189: 2, 190: 3, 191: 2, 192: 2, 193: 2, 194: 3, 195: 3, 196: 2, 197: 2, 198: 2, 199: 3, 200: 2, 201: 2, 202: 2, 203: 2, 204: 3, 205: 2, 206: 2, 207: 2, 208: 1, 209: 5, 210: 2, 211: 2, 212: 2, 213: 5, 214: 3, 215: 3, 216: 1, 217: 2, 218: 2, 219: 1, 220: 2, 221: 2, 222: 3, 223: 3, 224: 2, 225: 1, 226: 4, 227: 1, 228: 1, 229: 2, 230: 2, 231: 4, 232: 1, 233: 2, 234: 1, 235: 1, 236: 2, 237: 2, 238: 2, 239: 8, 240: 2, 241: 2, 242: 1, 243: 2, 244: 1, 245: 1, 246: 2, 247: 1, 248: 1, 249: 2, 250: 3, 251: 4, 252: 4, 253: 1, 254: 41, 255: 28, 256: 59, 257: 35, 258: 11, 259: 12, 260: 12, 261: 8, 262: 6, 263: 8, 264: 10, 265: 15, 266: 15, 267: 5, 268: 8, 269: 15, 270: 11, 271: 16, 272: 11, 273: 12, 274: 11, 275: 5, 276: 9, 277: 10, 278: 20, 279: 5, 280: 11, 281: 5, 282: 7, 283: 9, 284: 9, 285: 9, 286: 9, 287: 4, 288: 9, 289: 4, 290: 6, 291: 4, 292: 8, 293: 3, 294: 9, 295: 9, 296: 9, 297: 5, 298: 4, 299: 10, 300: 18, 301: 4, 302: 5, 303: 5, 304: 11, 305: 9, 306: 7, 307: 4, 308: 7, 309: 9, 310: 5, 311: 4, 312: 8, 313: 3, 314: 7, 315: 12, 316: 3, 317: 6, 318: 6, 319: 6, 320: 6, 321: 7, 322: 6, 323: 6, 324: 8, 325: 6, 326: 3, 327: 6, 328: 4, 329: 4, 330: 4, 331: 7, 332: 6, 333: 10, 334: 3, 335: 5, 336: 6, 337: 13, 338: 12, 339: 3, 340: 5, 341: 5, 342: 4, 343: 5, 344: 3, 345: 3, 346: 5, 347: 4, 348: 5, 349: 2, 350: 5, 351: 5, 352: 13, 353: 10, 354: 7, 355: 2, 356: 3, 357: 5, 358: 4, 359: 7, 360: 4, 361: 4, 362: 4, 363: 6, 364: 5, 365: 4, 366: 4, 367: 6, 368: 6, 369: 5, 370: 4, 371: 4, 372: 2, 373: 3, 374: 4, 375: 4, 376: 4, 377: 4, 378: 4, 379: 4, 380: 4, 381: 2, 382: 3, 383: 4, 384: 2, 385: 4, 386: 4, 387: 4, 388: 5, 389: 3, 390: 3, 391: 4, 392: 3, 393: 3, 394: 3, 395: 2, 396: 4, 397: 3, 398: 2, 399: 3, 400: 2, 401: 4, 402: 3, 403: 3, 404: 4, 405: 3, 406: 4, 407: 4, 408: 5, 409: 3, 410: 6, 411: 3, 412: 3, 413: 2, 414: 3, 415: 3, 416: 3, 417: 3, 418: 1, 419: 2, 420: 5, 421: 4, 422: 3, 423: 2, 424: 3, 425: 3, 426: 3, 427: 2, 428: 3, 429: 3, 430: 3, 431: 3, 432: 2, 433: 3, 434: 3, 435: 2, 436: 2, 437: 3, 438: 2, 439: 2, 440: 4, 441: 16, 442: 2, 443: 2, 444: 2, 445: 2, 446: 2, 447: 2, 448: 2, 449: 2, 450: 2, 451: 3, 452: 3, 453: 2, 454: 2, 455: 2, 456: 4, 457: 2, 458: 3, 459: 2, 460: 2, 461: 2, 462: 2, 463: 1, 464: 3, 465: 3, 466: 2, 467: 2, 468: 18, 469: 2, 470: 2, 471: 2, 472: 5, 473: 2, 474: 3, 475: 2, 476: 2, 477: 2, 478: 2, 479: 2, 480: 1, 481: 4, 482: 2, 483: 2, 484: 2, 485: 2, 486: 3, 487: 2, 488: 2, 489: 6, 490: 1, 491: 3, 492: 2, 493: 1, 494: 2, 495: 3, 496: 3, 497: 2, 498: 1, 499: 2, 500: 1, 501: 1, 502: 1, 503: 1, 504: 1, 505: 1, 506: 3, 507: 4, 508: 2, 509: 2, 510: 1, 511: 1, 512: 2, 513: 2, 514: 2, 515: 2, 516: 1, 517: 1, 518: 1, 519: 1, 520: 1, 521: 3, 522: 11, 523: 2, 524: 1, 525: 48, 526: 51, 527: 20, 528: 26, 529: 23, 530: 8, 531: 6, 532: 17, 533: 17, 534: 15, 535: 12, 536: 17, 537: 14, 538: 12, 539: 18, 540: 11, 541: 14, 542: 10, 543: 7, 544: 13, 545: 10, 546: 10, 547: 5, 548: 8, 549: 7, 550: 7, 551: 9, 552: 5, 553: 8, 554: 19, 555: 5, 556: 14, 557: 11, 558: 7, 559: 5, 560: 6, 561: 8, 562: 8, 563: 12, 564: 8, 565: 7, 566: 4, 567: 7, 568: 8, 569: 9, 570: 4, 571: 6, 572: 7, 573: 14, 574: 5, 575: 4, 576: 6, 577: 8, 578: 6, 579: 6, 580: 3, 581: 3, 582: 6, 583: 3, 584: 3, 585: 7, 586: 6, 587: 4, 588: 11, 589: 6, 590: 4, 591: 5, 592: 5, 593: 4, 594: 7, 595: 5, 596: 5, 597: 3, 598: 7, 599: 5, 600: 5, 601: 4, 602: 5, 603: 4, 604: 4, 605: 5, 606: 5, 607: 5, 608: 4, 609: 3, 610: 6, 611: 4, 612: 5, 613: 4, 614: 4, 615: 4, 616: 4, 617: 5, 618: 4, 619: 4, 620: 5, 621: 4, 622: 4, 623: 2, 624: 4, 625: 4, 626: 3, 627: 7, 628: 2, 629: 4, 630: 4, 631: 7, 632: 3, 633: 4, 634: 4, 635: 3, 636: 3, 637: 3, 638: 4, 639: 3, 640: 3, 641: 2, 642: 3, 643: 2, 644: 3, 645: 3, 646: 3, 647: 3, 648: 3, 649: 3, 650: 3, 651: 4, 652: 2, 653: 5, 654: 4, 655: 4, 656: 5, 657: 4, 658: 3, 659: 3, 660: 2, 661: 6, 662: 2, 663: 4, 664: 3, 665: 3, 666: 2, 667: 4, 668: 4, 669: 7, 670: 3, 671: 2, 672: 2, 673: 6, 674: 2, 675: 2, 676: 2, 677: 2, 678: 2, 679: 4, 680: 3, 681: 3, 682: 2, 683: 3, 684: 3, 685: 2, 686: 2, 687: 3, 688: 3, 689: 2, 690: 2, 691: 2, 692: 2, 693: 2, 694: 2, 695: 2, 696: 4, 697: 2, 698: 5, 699: 2, 700: 2, 701: 3, 702: 2, 703: 2, 704: 3, 705: 2, 706: 3, 707: 2, 708: 3, 709: 2, 710: 2, 711: 2, 712: 2, 713: 2, 714: 2, 715: 2, 716: 2, 717: 2, 718: 2, 719: 2, 720: 3, 721: 3, 722: 2, 723: 2, 724: 2, 725: 2, 726: 3, 727: 2, 728: 2, 729: 2, 730: 2, 731: 2, 732: 2, 733: 2, 734: 2, 735: 2, 736: 2, 737: 2, 738: 2, 739: 2, 740: 2, 741: 2, 742: 2, 743: 1, 744: 2, 745: 2, 746: 2, 747: 2, 748: 2, 749: 2, 750: 2, 751: 2, 752: 1, 753: 4, 754: 4, 755: 1, 756: 1, 757: 1, 758: 3, 759: 5, 760: 2, 761: 2, 762: 1, 763: 2, 764: 2, 765: 2, 766: 1, 767: 2, 768: 1, 769: 1, 770: 1, 771: 2, 772: 1, 773: 1, 774: 1, 775: 1, 776: 1, 777: 1, 778: 1}, 
    'status': {0: 'Extra', 1: 'Extra', 2: 'Extra', 3: 'Standard', 4: 'Extra', 5: 'Extra', 6: 'Extra', 7: 'Extra', 8: 'Standard', 9: 'Extra', 10: 'Extra', 11: 'Extra', 12: 'Extra', 13: 'Extra', 14: 'Standard', 15: 'Extra', 16: 'Extra', 17: 'Extra', 18: 'Extra', 19: 'Extra', 20: 'Extra', 21: 'Standard', 22: 'Standard', 23: 'Extra', 24: 'Standard', 25: 'Extra', 26: 'Extra', 27: 'Standard', 28: 'Extra', 29: 'Standard', 30: 'Extra', 31: 'Standard', 32: 'Extra', 33: 'Extra', 34: 'Standard', 35: 'Standard', 36: 'Standard', 37: 'Standard', 38: 'Standard', 39: 'Standard', 40: 'Extra', 41: 'Standard', 42: 'Extra', 43: 'Standard', 44: 'Standard', 45: 'Extra', 46: 'Standard', 47: 'Standard', 48: 'Standard', 49: 'Standard', 50: 'Standard', 51: 'Standard', 52: 'Standard', 53: 'Extra', 54: 'Standard', 55: 'Extra', 56: 'Standard', 57: 'Extra', 58: 'Standard', 59: 'Standard', 60: 'Extra', 61: 'Standard', 62: 'Extra', 63: 'Standard', 64: 'Extra', 65: 'Standard', 66: 'Standard', 67: 'Extra', 68: 'Standard', 69: 'Standard', 70: 'Extra', 71: 'Standard', 72: 'Extra', 73: 'Standard', 74: 'Standard', 75: 'Standard', 76: 'Standard', 77: 'Standard', 78: 'Standard', 79: 'Standard', 80: 'Standard', 81: 'Standard', 82: 'Standard', 83: 'Standard', 84: 'Standard', 85: 'Standard', 86: 'Standard', 87: 'Standard', 88: 'Standard', 89: 'Extra', 90: 'Extra', 91: 'Standard', 92: 'Extra', 93: 'Standard', 94: 'Standard', 95: 'Standard', 96: 'Standard', 97: 'Extra', 98: 'Standard', 99: 'Standard', 100: 'Standard', 101: 'Standard', 102: 'Standard', 103: 'Standard', 104: 'Standard', 105: 'Standard', 106: 'Standard', 107: 'Standard', 108: 'Standard', 109: 'Standard', 110: 'Standard', 111: 'Extra', 112: 'Standard', 113: 'Extra', 114: 'Standard', 115: 'Extra', 116: 'Standard', 117: 'Standard', 118: 'Extra', 119: 'Standard', 120: 'Standard', 121: 'Standard', 122: 'Standard', 123: 'Standard', 124: 'Extra', 125: 'Standard', 126: 'Standard', 127: 'Standard', 128: 'Standard', 129: 'Standard', 130: 'Extra', 131: 'Standard', 132: 'Standard', 133: 'Standard', 134: 'Standard', 135: 'Standard', 136: 'Standard', 137: 'Standard', 138: 'Standard', 139: 'Extra', 140: 'Standard', 141: 'Standard', 142: 'Standard', 143: 'Standard', 144: 'Standard', 145: 'Standard', 146: 'Standard', 147: 'Standard', 148: 'Standard', 149: 'Standard', 150: 'Extra', 151: 'Standard', 152: 'Standard', 153: 'Standard', 154: 'Extra', 155: 'Standard', 156: 'Extra', 157: 'Extra', 158: 'Standard', 159: 'Standard', 160: 'Standard', 161: 'Standard', 162: 'Standard', 163: 'Extra', 164: 'Standard', 165: 'Standard', 166: 'Extra', 167: 'Standard', 168: 'Standard', 169: 'Standard', 170: 'Standard', 171: 'Standard', 172: 'Standard', 173: 'Standard', 174: 'Standard', 175: 'Standard', 176: 'Standard', 177: 'Standard', 178: 'Standard', 179: 'Standard', 180: 'Standard', 181: 'Standard', 182: 'Standard', 183: 'Standard', 184: 'Standard', 185: 'Standard', 186: 'Standard', 187: 'Standard', 188: 'Standard', 189: 'Standard', 190: 'Standard', 191: 'Standard', 192: 'Standard', 193: 'Standard', 194: 'Standard', 195: 'Standard', 196: 'Standard', 197: 'Standard', 198: 'Standard', 199: 'Standard', 200: 'Standard', 201: 'Standard', 202: 'Standard', 203: 'Standard', 204: 'Standard', 205: 'Standard', 206: 'Standard', 207: 'Standard', 208: 'Standard', 209: 'Standard', 210: 'Standard', 211: 'Extra', 212: 'Standard', 213: 'Standard', 214: 'Standard', 215: 'Standard', 216: 'Standard', 217: 'Standard', 218: 'Standard', 219: 'Standard', 220: 'Standard', 221: 'Standard', 222: 'Standard', 223: 'Standard', 224: 'Standard', 225: 'Standard', 226: 'Standard', 227: 'Standard', 228: 'Standard', 229: 'Standard', 230: 'Standard', 231: 'Standard', 232: 'Standard', 233: 'Standard', 234: 'Standard', 235: 'Standard', 236: 'Standard', 237: 'Standard', 238: 'Standard', 239: 'Standard', 240: 'Standard', 241: 'Standard', 242: 'Standard', 243: 'Standard', 244: 'Standard', 245: 'Standard', 246: 'Standard', 247: 'Extra', 248: 'Standard', 249: 'Standard', 250: 'Standard', 251: 'Extra', 252: 'Extra', 253: 'Standard', 254: 'Extra', 255: 'Extra', 256: 'Extra', 257: 'Extra', 258: 'Extra', 259: 'Extra', 260: 'Extra', 261: 'Extra', 262: 'Extra', 263: 'Standard', 264: 'Extra', 265: 'Standard', 266: 'Extra', 267: 'Extra', 268: 'Standard', 269: 'Standard', 270: 'Extra', 271: 'Extra', 272: 'Extra', 273: 'Standard', 274: 'Extra', 275: 'Standard', 276: 'Extra', 277: 'Standard', 278: 'Standard', 279: 'Standard', 280: 'Standard', 281: 'Standard', 282: 'Standard', 283: 'Standard', 284: 'Extra', 285: 'Extra', 286: 'Standard', 287: 'Standard', 288: 'Extra', 289: 'Standard', 290: 'Standard', 291: 'Extra', 292: 'Extra', 293: 'Extra', 294: 'Extra', 295: 'Standard', 296: 'Standard', 297: 'Extra', 298: 'Extra', 299: 'Standard', 300: 'Standard', 301: 'Extra', 302: 'Standard', 303: 'Standard', 304: 'Standard', 305: 'Standard', 306: 'Standard', 307: 'Extra', 308: 'Standard', 309: 'Standard', 310: 'Standard', 311: 'Extra', 312: 'Extra', 313: 'Extra', 314: 'Standard', 315: 'Standard', 316: 'Standard', 317: 'Extra', 318: 'Standard', 319: 'Extra', 320: 'Standard', 321: 'Extra', 322: 'Standard', 323: 'Extra', 324: 'Standard', 325: 'Extra', 326: 'Standard', 327: 'Standard', 328: 'Standard', 329: 'Extra', 330: 'Standard', 331: 'Standard', 332: 'Standard', 333: 'Standard', 334: 'Standard', 335: 'Extra', 336: 'Standard', 337: 'Standard', 338: 'Standard', 339: 'Extra', 340: 'Extra', 341: 'Extra', 342: 'Standard', 343: 'Standard', 344: 'Extra', 345: 'Standard', 346: 'Extra', 347: 'Standard', 348: 'Extra', 349: 'Standard', 350: 'Extra', 351: 'Standard', 352: 'Standard', 353: 'Standard', 354: 'Standard', 355: 'Standard', 356: 'Standard', 357: 'Standard', 358: 'Standard', 359: 'Standard', 360: 'Standard', 361: 'Standard', 362: 'Standard', 363: 'Extra', 364: 'Standard', 365: 'Standard', 366: 'Standard', 367: 'Extra', 368: 'Standard', 369: 'Standard', 370: 'Standard', 371: 'Extra', 372: 'Standard', 373: 'Standard', 374: 'Standard', 375: 'Standard', 376: 'Standard', 377: 'Standard', 378: 'Standard', 379: 'Extra', 380: 'Standard', 381: 'Standard', 382: 'Standard', 383: 'Extra', 384: 'Standard', 385: 'Standard', 386: 'Standard', 387: 'Standard', 388: 'Standard', 389: 'Standard', 390: 'Standard', 391: 'Standard', 392: 'Standard', 393: 'Standard', 394: 'Standard', 395: 'Standard', 396: 'Standard', 397: 'Standard', 398: 'Standard', 399: 'Extra', 400: 'Standard', 401: 'Standard', 402: 'Standard', 403: 'Standard', 404: 'Standard', 405: 'Standard', 406: 'Standard', 407: 'Standard', 408: 'Standard', 409: 'Extra', 410: 'Standard', 411: 'Standard', 412: 'Standard', 413: 'Standard', 414: 'Standard', 415: 'Standard', 416: 'Standard', 417: 'Standard', 418: 'Extra', 419: 'Standard', 420: 'Standard', 421: 'Standard', 422: 'Standard', 423: 'Standard', 424: 'Standard', 425: 'Standard', 426: 'Standard', 427: 'Standard', 428: 'Standard', 429: 'Standard', 430: 'Standard', 431: 'Standard', 432: 'Standard', 433: 'Extra', 434: 'Standard', 435: 'Standard', 436: 'Standard', 437: 'Standard', 438: 'Standard', 439: 'Standard', 440: 'Standard', 441: 'Standard', 442: 'Standard', 443: 'Standard', 444: 'Standard', 445: 'Standard', 446: 'Standard', 447: 'Standard', 448: 'Standard', 449: 'Standard', 450: 'Standard', 451: 'Standard', 452: 'Standard', 453: 'Standard', 454: 'Standard', 455: 'Standard', 456: 'Standard', 457: 'Standard', 458: 'Extra', 459: 'Extra', 460: 'Extra', 461: 'Standard', 462: 'Standard', 463: 'Standard', 464: 'Standard', 465: 'Standard', 466: 'Standard', 467: 'Standard', 468: 'Standard', 469: 'Standard', 470: 'Standard', 471: 'Extra', 472: 'Standard', 473: 'Standard', 474: 'Standard', 475: 'Standard', 476: 'Standard', 477: 'Extra', 478: 'Standard', 479: 'Standard', 480: 'Standard', 481: 'Standard', 482: 'Standard', 483: 'Standard', 484: 'Standard', 485: 'Standard', 486: 'Standard', 487: 'Standard', 488: 'Extra', 489: 'Standard', 490: 'Standard', 491: 'Standard', 492: 'Standard', 493: 'Standard', 494: 'Standard', 495: 'Standard', 496: 'Standard', 497: 'Standard', 498: 'Standard', 499: 'Extra', 500: 'Standard', 501: 'Standard', 502: 'Standard', 503: 'Standard', 504: 'Extra', 505: 'Standard', 506: 'Extra', 507: 'Standard', 508: 'Standard', 509: 'Standard', 510: 'Standard', 511: 'Extra', 512: 'Standard', 513: 'Standard', 514: 'Standard', 515: 'Extra', 516: 'Standard', 517: 'Standard', 518: 'Standard', 519: 'Extra', 520: 'Extra', 521: 'Standard', 522: 'Standard', 523: 'Standard', 524: 'Extra', 525: 'Extra', 526: 'Extra', 527: 'Standard', 528: 'Standard', 529: 'Extra', 530: 'Extra', 531: 'Extra', 532: 'Extra', 533: 'Extra', 534: 'Standard', 535: 'Extra', 536: 'Standard', 537: 'Standard', 538: 'Standard', 539: 'Extra', 540: 'Extra', 541: 'Extra', 542: 'Extra', 543: 'Extra', 544: 'Extra', 545: 'Standard', 546: 'Extra', 547: 'Extra', 548: 'Extra', 549: 'Standard', 550: 'Extra', 551: 'Extra', 552: 'Standard', 553: 'Standard', 554: 'Extra', 555: 'Extra', 556: 'Standard', 557: 'Extra', 558: 'Extra', 559: 'Extra', 560: 'Extra', 561: 'Extra', 562: 'Extra', 563: 'Standard', 564: 'Standard', 565: 'Extra', 566: 'Extra', 567: 'Extra', 568: 'Extra', 569: 'Standard', 570: 'Standard', 571: 'Extra', 572: 'Extra', 573: 'Standard', 574: 'Extra', 575: 'Standard', 576: 'Extra', 577: 'Extra', 578: 'Extra', 579: 'Extra', 580: 'Extra', 581: 'Standard', 582: 'Extra', 583: 'Standard', 584: 'Standard', 585: 'Extra', 586: 'Standard', 587: 'Standard', 588: 'Extra', 589: 'Standard', 590: 'Standard', 591: 'Extra', 592: 'Standard', 593: 'Standard', 594: 'Standard', 595: 'Extra', 596: 'Extra', 597: 'Extra', 598: 'Standard', 599: 'Standard', 600: 'Standard', 601: 'Standard', 602: 'Extra', 603: 'Extra', 604: 'Extra', 605: 'Standard', 606: 'Standard', 607: 'Standard', 608: 'Standard', 609: 'Standard', 610: 'Extra', 611: 'Standard', 612: 'Standard', 613: 'Standard', 614: 'Standard', 615: 'Standard', 616: 'Extra', 617: 'Standard', 618: 'Standard', 619: 'Standard', 620: 'Standard', 621: 'Standard', 622: 'Extra', 623: 'Standard', 624: 'Standard', 625: 'Standard', 626: 'Extra', 627: 'Standard', 628: 'Standard', 629: 'Standard', 630: 'Extra', 631: 'Extra', 632: 'Standard', 633: 'Extra', 634: 'Standard', 635: 'Standard', 636: 'Standard', 637: 'Standard', 638: 'Standard', 639: 'Standard', 640: 'Standard', 641: 'Standard', 642: 'Standard', 643: 'Standard', 644: 'Standard', 645: 'Standard', 646: 'Extra', 647: 'Extra', 648: 'Extra', 649: 'Standard', 650: 'Standard', 651: 'Standard', 652: 'Extra', 653: 'Standard', 654: 'Standard', 655: 'Standard', 656: 'Standard', 657: 'Standard', 658: 'Standard', 659: 'Standard', 660: 'Standard', 661: 'Standard', 662: 'Standard', 663: 'Standard', 664: 'Standard', 665: 'Standard', 666: 'Standard', 667: 'Extra', 668: 'Standard', 669: 'Standard', 670: 'Standard', 671: 'Standard', 672: 'Extra', 673: 'Extra', 674: 'Standard', 675: 'Standard', 676: 'Standard', 677: 'Standard', 678: 'Standard', 679: 'Extra', 680: 'Standard', 681: 'Extra', 682: 'Standard', 683: 'Standard', 684: 'Standard', 685: 'Standard', 686: 'Standard', 687: 'Extra', 688: 'Standard', 689: 'Standard', 690: 'Standard', 691: 'Standard', 692: 'Standard', 693: 'Standard', 694: 'Standard', 695: 'Standard', 696: 'Standard', 697: 'Standard', 698: 'Standard', 699: 'Extra', 700: 'Standard', 701: 'Standard', 702: 'Standard', 703: 'Standard', 704: 'Standard', 705: 'Standard', 706: 'Standard', 707: 'Standard', 708: 'Standard', 709: 'Standard', 710: 'Standard', 711: 'Standard', 712: 'Extra', 713: 'Standard', 714: 'Standard', 715: 'Standard', 716: 'Standard', 717: 'Standard', 718: 'Standard', 719: 'Standard', 720: 'Standard', 721: 'Standard', 722: 'Extra', 723: 'Standard', 724: 'Standard', 725: 'Standard', 726: 'Standard', 727: 'Standard', 728: 'Standard', 729: 'Extra', 730: 'Standard', 731: 'Standard', 732: 'Standard', 733: 'Standard', 734: 'Standard', 735: 'Standard', 736: 'Standard', 737: 'Standard', 738: 'Standard', 739: 'Standard', 740: 'Standard', 741: 'Standard', 742: 'Standard', 743: 'Standard', 744: 'Extra', 745: 'Standard', 746: 'Standard', 747: 'Standard', 748: 'Standard', 749: 'Standard', 750: 'Standard', 751: 'Standard', 752: 'Standard', 753: 'Standard', 754: 'Standard', 755: 'Standard', 756: 'Extra', 757: 'Standard', 758: 'Standard', 759: 'Standard', 760: 'Extra', 761: 'Standard', 762: 'Standard', 763: 'Standard', 764: 'Standard', 765: 'Standard', 766: 'Standard', 767: 'Standard', 768: 'Standard', 769: 'Standard', 770: 'Standard', 771: 'Standard', 772: 'Extra', 773: 'Extra', 774: 'Standard', 775: 'Standard', 776: 'Standard', 777: 'Extra', 778: 'Standard'}
}
```

I'm trying to visualize as simple as possible the overall advantage of `Extra` vs `Standard` (I.E: 'What is the edge of `Extra` over `Standard`?)

```
df[['views_per_day', 'status']].groupby('status').quantile(0.85).plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a [`boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)? (eventually with a log scale):

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='status', y='views_per_day')
ax.set_yscale("log")
```

output:

[image]

Or a [`violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html):

```
ax = sns.violinplot(data=df, x='status', y='views_per_day')
```

[image]

Comment: @Barry, I don't see a particular flaw in your approach. You decide to show a single value to describe your data. This comes with the drawback of simplifying what the real data is. Here, whether you use the median or 85 percentile, both show a higher value for "Extra". I like to show a graph that gives an idea of the distribution (box plot/violin plot), but your approach is not misleading.